# MongoDB 3.2 on Windows 8.1, I can not start the service

Tags: windows, mongodb, service

I am running mongoDB 3.2 the OS is Windows 8.1. 
I can not seem to start the net service for MongoDB
I started Mongod OK and it is listening 
I started Mongo as well
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.0
connecting to: test

> show dbs
>   local  0.000GB

net start MongoDB
The service name is invalid.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185.

Created the mongo service via the sc command. From an admin window.
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe --service --config=\"C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"

Still getting error when trying to start the service
Anyone has come across this problem and can has a solution please share it.

Comment: Does it show up in the services manager?

Comment: Yes the service is visible when I try to start it I get the error Windows could not start the MongoDB serviceon the local computer and Error 1053:The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Comment: Here is the sc command used C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe --service --config=" C:\mongoDB\cfg\mongod_win8.cfg\ DisplayName= MongoDB start= auto

Comment: The image Path in the registery looks wrong note the hanging quote after config
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe --service --config=" C:\mongoDB\cfg\mongod_win8.cfg\ DisplayName= MongoDB start= auto

Comment: Should I change the image path to 
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin\mongod.exe --service --config=" C:\mongoDB\cfg\mongod_win8.cfg" DisplayName= MongoDB start= auto

Comment: Try that and also try executing the command to from the command line, minus the --service of course

Comment: Succeeded in starting the service. Changed entry to: